# Merge arrays made in loop

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have a set of arrays made as a result of query from mysql table, made in "while" loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $k_id =  $row['kw'];
    $path[$level] = $k_id;

    if(array_search('7', $path)) {
        $it = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($path));
        $t1 = array();
        foreach ( $it as $v ) {
            $var = array("no" => $v,"to" => 0);
            if ($it->hasNext()) {
                $var["to"] = $it->getInnerIterator()->current();
            }
            $t1[] = $var;
        }

        extract($t1, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "t1");

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($t1); $i++) {
            $dmp = print_r($t1[$i], result);
            echo $dmp."<br />";
        }
    }     
}
```

Result of echo $dmp is a set of arrays:

```
Array ( [no] => 2 [to] => 1 )
Array ( [no] => 1 [to] => 4 )
Array ( [no] => 4 [to] => 7 )
Array ( [no] => 7 [to] => 0 )
Array ( [no] => 2 [to] => 1 )
Array ( [no] => 1 [to] => 5 )
Array ( [no] => 5 [to] => 7 )
Array ( [no] => 7 [to] => 0 )
Array ( [no] => 2 [to] => 1 )
Array ( [no] => 1 [to] => 6 )
Array ( [no] => 6 [to] => 7 )
Array ( [no] => 7 [to] => 0 )
Array ( [no] => 2 [to] => 1 )
Array ( [no] => 1 [to] => 3 )
Array ( [no] => 3 [to] => 7 )
Array ( [no] => 7 [to] => 0 )
```

My question is how to merge arrays with the same "no" key values

Var_dump before mysql_fetch:

```
array(0) { } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "1" } array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "4" }
```

As a result I would like to get arrays I could easy produce such a code from :

```
 "nodeTo": "4", 
    "nodeFrom": "1"

"nodeTo": "5", 
    "nodeFrom": "1"

"nodeTo": "6", 
    "nodeFrom": "1"

"nodeTo": "3", 
    "nodeFrom": "1"

    "id": "1"
```

Comment: What should the end structure look like?

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($path);` before the `mysql_fetch_array()` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would really advice you to create the correct array structure directly when fetching results from sql. This will save you an additonal foreach loop.**

For completeness, I've prepared an example for you, how you can do it like you supposed: (for fun ;) )

```
$a = array (
    array ('no' => 2, 'to' => 1), //  |___ will be merged
    array ('no' => 2, 'to' => 1), //  |
    array ('no' => 2, 'to' => 2),
    array ('no' => 3, 'to' => 2)
);

$result = array();
foreach($a as $item) {
    if(!array_key_exists($item['no'], $result)) {
        $result[$item['no']] = array($item['to']);
    } else if(!in_array($item['to'], $result[$item['no']], TRUE)) {
        $result[$item['no']][] = $item['to'];
    }
}

// get all to values with no=2 :
$elements = $result[2];
```

A var_dump of the result array after conversion may help to understand what's going on:

```
//
var_dump($result);

/* Output:

array(2) {
  [2] =>  <---- 'no' value as index
  array(2) {
    [0] =>    -
    int(1)     |__ different 'to' values
    [1] =>     |
    int(2)    -
  }
  [3] => <---- 'no' value as index
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    int(2)   <------ 'to' value for 'no'==3
  }
}

*/
```

As I said, you should create this array structure directly when fetching results form sql. Unfortunately, without having the contents of `$path` I cannot say how to achieve this.

Comment: thank you, it works. I put var_dump as you requested into my question above

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
 $t1[] = $var;
```

With

```
$t1[$v][] = $var;
```

It would be grouped based on ID ... Example on how to output the result :

```
foreach ( $t1 as $no => $group ) {
    echo "Merge $no <br />" ;
    foreach ( $group as $list ) {
        var_dump($list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Merge 2
array(2) { ["no"]=> string(1) "2" ["to"]=> string(1) "1" } Merge 1
array(2) { ["no"]=> string(1) "1" ["to"]=> string(1) "5" } Merge 5
array(2) { ["no"]=> string(1) "5" ["to"]=> string(1) "7" } Merge 7 the result is more less like this for every array separately

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($t1 as $dmp) {
    $combined[$dmp["no"]][] = $dmp["to"];
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
        )

)
```

Comment: @user2056916 below `extract($t1, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "t1");`

Comment: hmm I don't get the same result :( maybe because my arrays are made in loop separately